# Scheduling 40+ colab notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, scheduled-tasks

I want to schedule about 40 google colab notebooks to run each Monday morning. I have Colab Pro + account since I'm dealing with big data.

I wanted to schedule the notebooks with "scheduler" option that is on left hand side but colab allows me only to schedule 2 notebooks.
Does anyone know what are my alternatives?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use code to lunch the rest of the code.

Comment: Hi D.L. , thanks!
Do you have code for that?

Comment: the question at this point is to generic to answer without being marked down, but you can easily use one script to import other scripts to run at certain intervals or specific times. And there is also **Event scheduler** like this: `import sched, time`.